# Why does \index lose text with continuation lines?

Tags: indexing

I have a document with large index strings and wish to split them into multiple lines for legibility! The first two \index commands work as expected, but the one split after the @ generates only G instead of G on one line and an indented I with a page number on the next line.

The fix suggested by A Gold Man works fine:

```
\documentclass[draft]{amsart}

% suppress verbatim for \index
\newcommand \indexfold [1] {\index{#1}}

% Generate paired subindex entries
\newcommand \indexpair [2] {\index{#1!#2}\index{#2!#1}}

% Generate paired subsubindex entries 2!3, 3!2, 1!2!3, 1!3!2
\newcommand \indextriple [3]%
  {%
    \index{#2!#3}%
    \index{#3!#2}%
    \index{#1!#2!#3}%
    \index{#1!#3!#2}%
  }

\makeindex

\begin{document}

\begin{flushleft}

{\textbackslash}index\{A!B@C\}
\index{A!B@C}

{\textbackslash}index\{D!\% \\
  E@F\}
\index{D!%
  E@F}

{\textbackslash}index\{G!H@\% \\
  I\}
\index{G!H@%
  I}

{\textbackslash}indexfold\{text1!sublabel1@\% \\
  subtext1\}
\indexfold{text1!sublabel1@%
  subtext1}

{\textbackslash}indexpair\{\{text2\}\{sublabel2@subtext2\}\}
\indexpair{text2}{sublabel2@subtext2}

{\textbackslash}indextriple\% \\
    \{text3\}\% \\
    \{sublabel3@subtext3\}\% \\
    \{subsublabel3@subsubtext3\}
\indextriple%
    {text3}%
    {sublabel3@subtext3}%
    {subsublabel3@subsubtext3}

\end{flushleft}

\printindex

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The index command takes the argument in literally, and only gets proccessed once typeset. this means that your comment character is actually read in as a literal % sign. If you take a look at your .idx file, you'll find the entries:

```
\indexentry{D!%   E@F}{1}
\indexentry{G!H@%   I}{1}
```

neither of which are correct, seeing as you aren't sorting your second entry under %, and you want anything after that % in the third entry to be read.

You could work around this by defining a command which takes an argument and feeds it to `\index` as follows:

```
\def\myindex#1{\index{#1}}
```

which will have TeX first scan the input, and correctly ignore the %.

Answer (score 3):

The argument to `\index` is read in “verbatim”, so with your code the `.idx` file will be like

```
\indexentry{A!B@C}{1}
\indexentry{D!%   E@F}{1}
\indexentry{G!H@%   I}{1}
```

and, upon a MakeIndex run, the `.ind` file will be

```
\begin{theindex}

  \item A
    \subitem C, 1

  \indexspace

  \item D
    \subitem F, 1

  \indexspace

  \item G
    \subitem %   I, 1

\end{theindex}
```

So, no: you cannot use `%` for this purpose, unless you make `%` back into a comment character:

```
\documentclass[draft]{amsart}
\usepackage{xpatch}

\makeindex

\makeatletter
\xpatchcmd{\index}
  {\@sanitize}
  {\@sanitize\catcode`\%=14 }
  {}{}
\makeatother


\begin{document}

{\textbackslash}index\{A!B@C\}
\index{A!B@C}

{\textbackslash}index\{D!\% \\
  E@F\}
\index{D!%
  E@F}

{\textbackslash}index\{G!H@\% \\
  I\}
\index{G!H@%
  I}

\printindex

\end{document}
```

Beware that spaces at the beginning of lines will not be ignored. With this, the `.idx` file will look like

```
\indexentry{A!B@C}{1}
\indexentry{D!  E@F}{1}
\indexentry{G!H@  I}{1}
```

Yes, you saw right: `\%` doesn't go through. You can't have both, I'm afraid.